# how to compare two different tables in pl/sql block

Tags: sql, oracle

How to compare two different tables in pl/sql block

TABLE A- T_tABLE1

```
BIZDAY  DATE    
ACID    NUMBER(12,0)    
TYPE    VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)
ADJDATE DATE        
SOURCE  VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)
DATEUPDATED DATE
```

TABLE 2:

```
BIZDAY  DATE    
ACID    NUMBER  
TYPE    VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
ADJDATE DATE    
SOURCE  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
DATEUPDATED DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

**To get the count of the differences**

```
select count(*) 
  from 
(
( select * from table1
  minus 
  select * from table2 )
union all
( select * from table2 
  minus
  select * from table1 )
);
```

will tell you how many rows are in table1 not in table2 + in table2 not in table1

**To get the actual data comparison**

```
select *
  from 
(
( select * from table1
  minus 
  select * from table2 )
union all
( select * from table2 
  minus
  select * from table1 )
);
```

**Another approach:**

Before 11gR1 use [DBMS_RECTIFIER_DIFF](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28327/rarrectdifpac.htm#i94795)

From 11gR1 or above use [DBMS_COMPARISON](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_comparison.htm#CHDHEFFJ)

Comment: Thank you .. If i wanted to compare with multiple tables , how do i compare.

Comment: I wanted to check the feilds (values) from both the tables. The structure Might be same , but the values might differ. Can some1 please help

Comment: @user3318635 check the updated answer for data check and in build tools.

Answer (score 0):

If your tables have primary keys, you can also use a full outer join to find the differences between the two tables. Please see this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0c3eb/2).